# How to install deleted package in SDK Manager?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, google-api

So I have deleted Google APIs package in SDK Manager and I want to install it again, but it has been deleted completely (there is no icon), so I can't do it. I downloaded android sdk from their website, but unfortunately it isn't there as well. The other thing I noticed is that now under `AppData\Local\Android\` are two sdk folders - `sdk` and `android-sdk`. First one contains the sdk that android studio uses, the second one the one that I downloaded. Should I do something about it? How can I download Google APIs again?

That's how my sdk manager looks:
[image]